# How to group multiple date|data columns to one single date column on the left?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, spreadsheet, format

I've got a large set of data that looks like:

[image: this]

and I've been trying to format it so that instead of having a column of dates for each item, there's only one column of dates on the left. The problem is some of them have missing dates and I don't know how to insert a blank cell for those dates as well as make all the data match the correct date.

Comment: I would suggest developing a VBA or Power Query solution. If you have O365, a complex formula might be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do NOT have O365, I suggest a VBA or Power Query solution.

However, if you have Excel O365, you can try the following:

- Create a Table from your data (my Table name is `Table5`; adjust the formulas to match your table name.

  - Doing so will automatically place Headers in the blank columns with names like `ColumnN` where `N` is a number

Given that my results start in A22 (see below)

Formulas:

- A sorted list of the unique dates from your original table:

  ```
    A23: =SORT(UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,INDEX(Table5,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table5)),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(Table5)/2,1,2))) & "</s></t>","//s")))
  ```
- A list of the Corporations:

  ```
    B22: =FILTER(Table5[#Headers],ISERR(FIND("Column",Table5[#Headers])))
  ```
- Return the matching values

  ```
    B23: =LET(x,INDEX(Table5,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table5)),SEQUENCE(,2,MATCH(B$22,Table5[#Headers],0)-1)),y,XLOOKUP($A23,INDEX(x,0,1),INDEX(x,0,2),""),y)
  ```

Select `B23` and fill down and across to fill the results table.

[image]

***Explanation of Unique Dates formula:***

```
INDEX(Table5,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table5)),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(Table5)/2,1,2))
```

will return a table that contains only the odd numbered columns (which are the date columns)

```
TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,the_odd_column_table)
```

joins all of the entries in those date columns into a single string with the specified delimiter

```
FILTERXML("<t><s>" & the_joined_string & "</s></t>","//s")))
```

creates a XML and then returns an array of the nodes *(which will be the dates from the original table)*.

```
SORT(UNIQUE(the_dates_array))
```

does the obvious.

Comment: Thanks for having a look, the formula for B22 worked perfectly but not the one for A23. I made sure that the table was also called table5 but all it gave was #VALUE!. Since B23 references A23, I assume that was also why that cell didn't work and only gave #VALUE! as well. I just installed O365 so I'm not sure if there are different versions of it that may not support the formula.

Comment: Do you have a Mac? Or are you running on Windows?

Comment: I'm running on Windows. Would it help if I tried it on mac?
If it helps, I can manually enter the dates since I know when the earliest and last one is, although I don't know how to adapt the formula to use those dates instead of the generated one.

Comment: @froghurtbeaver No, I wouldn't expect it to run on a Mac. How many rows and columns in your data?

Comment: It goes from A-MT, 1-771

Comment: @froghurtbeaver In that case, I don't think you can use a formula approach. Intermediate steps will exceed that `32,767` character limitation of `TEXTJOIN`. You'll need to use either Power Query or VBA to handle data of that size.

Comment: @froghurtbeaver I just re-read one of your comments. And the answer is that YES, if you  can enter the dates manually, then the formulas within the table( `B23:D29` in my example) should work just fine and enable you to avoid using VBA or Power Query.  If not, I can post a Power Query solution.

Comment: I gave it a go and worked perfectly, using the dates I made with your formula didn't automatically populate all the cells, only one corporation. But that was an easy autofill. Thanks a lot for your help!